Single-suffix rule not invoked (as expected)
The post Need a makefile dependency rule that can handle missing files sounded promising for my problem. Unfortunately the single-suffix rule doesn't work for me as expected...
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .gen
 
# .gen:   --> "building lib using lib.c lib.gen" when file present
# %.gen: --> "code generation from lib.gen started" when file **NOT** present
#             "building lib using lib.c lib.gen" when file present
.gen:
    @echo code generation from $@ started...

# library is built with source files generated
# from lib.gen
lib: lib.c lib.gen    
    @echo building $@ using $^
 
bin: lib
    @echo building $@

I want to build a library which has a "dynamic portion". Depending on the contents of lib.gen additional source files may be added (that's another story). Therefore when encountering a .gen file a generator (script) shall be invoked using $@.
Single-suffix rule should read

.gen:

but it is not hit.
Actually -d tells me (even with .PHONY : lib):
   Found an implicit rule for 'lib.gen'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'lib.gen'.
  No need to remake target 'lib.gen'.

I played around and using

%.gen:

the recipe is hit but only if lin.gen does not exist...
The latter looks like a pattern rule. Actually

% : %.gen

(as per O'Reilly book) also is not invoked.
Is there a chance to get an implicit rule invoked?
PS: I am using single-suffix as generator will produce both .c and .h files.

It would be easier to answer if you described your problem as, "I have the following files in a clean directory: .  when I run make I want the following commands to be executed: .  when I modify file XXX and run make again I want the following commands to be executed: ".  Since I don't understand the question I can't tell for sure but I think you are misunderstanding what a single-suffix implicit rule is or how it works.  A single suffix rule .foo: is identical to the pattern rule %: %.foo.

I don't understand what you want.  It would be helpful if you explained a complete example of what operations you want to happen.
However, in make all targets are only run if they are out of date.  It doesn't matter whether the rule used is implicit or explicit.  A target is out of date if (a) it does not exist, or (b) it does exist but its modification time is older than one or more of its prerequisites.  Or, if you declare it to be .PHONY.
Based on the output you show above, it seems that your lib.gen file does exist, and you do not provide any prerequisites for it, so make considers it up to date and does not rebuild it.  This is exactly the behavior I would expect.

I found a nice example in autoconf manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.63/html_node/Single-Suffix-Rules.html
 $ cat Makefile
 .SUFFIXES: .in
 .in:
         cp $< $@
 $ make foo
 cp foo.in foo

This is what I expect: getting a "foo" make sees there's a "foo.in" in directory. And thus execute the single-suffix rule. No prerequisites (aka dependencies) needed!

I didn't say you needed to have a prerequisite to use the rule.  I said, you have to have a prerequisite to have the target be updated if it already exists.  Nothing about the autoconf example contradicts that.  In other words, if you run make foo and foo doesn't exist, make will run the recipe to create it.  If you run make foo and foo already exists, make will not run the recipe to update it, because it has no prerequisites.

The makefile needs to look like this in order to work:
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .gen
 
.gen:
    @echo code generation from $< started...

bin: lib
    @echo building $@

# library is built with source files generated
# from lib.gen
lib: lib.c lib_cfg    
    @echo building $@ using $^

In last rule the ".gen" in dependency has to be ommitted!
NB: lib_cfg.gen file must exist.
